# How do I access the output of sql in scala?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'd like to get access to the results from a sql query that is getting sent over to a redshift database in scala.

```
val test = spark.sql("""
SELECT * FROM my_table 
LIMIT 100""")

test.show
```

When I check the class it appears to be a sql data set.

```
test.getClass
res52: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
```

Unfortunately, it returns this error.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange SinglePartition
```

How do I show the top results from my sql dataset?

Comment: does this help? https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html

Comment: I looked around, but I don't see anything that corresponds to my problem.

Comment: okay, it has stuff in there about outputting sql results from a data frame, but I don't really do scala and was just poking the thread with a stick. hope someone can help you.